# PayPal Donation/Giving API incontext

Tags: paypal

how do I make donation paypal api call incontext? There are documentation for integrating the donate button, but it opens a new window. Trying to figure out how to build the in-context experience for the donation/giving API calls.

Comment: What code do you have for this so far? Are you adapting existing code for display buttons, or writing your own? Please add the code you've got so far to your post if you can - it will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: I am trying to use the existing adaptive Payments "Pay" API. Only thing i am confused is how to notify paypal that the payment is for donation/charity purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

PayPal automatically takes care of donation/charity when the receiver's email is tied to 501c3 organization.

And for the incontext experience, just followed the documentation of dg adaptive payments flow. Here is the guide for sample code - https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro

Comment: Does that mean that the user donor will get a receipt they can use for tax purposes?

Comment: Where did you get this information?  I've been searching paypal's documentation for information about how to use adaptive payments for 501c3 organizations.